# Using Swagger UI Express / @nestjs/swagger, What is best practice to edit API response codes, descriptions and other properties

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, openapi

So I currently already have the swagger UI set up with the page and everything, but I want to edit the .json file (so I can provide descriptions, error codes and stuff but all in one document). Was just wondering where I should be locating my swagger.json or swagger.yaml file to be able to adjust the API??

If not, what's the best practice for documenting parameters, response codes and descriptions WITHOUT having to do it tediously one by one like below...

[image]

Any advice on using swagger with nestjs applications would be much appreciated :) Still very new with using it

Comment: Swagger.json file is generated at runtime, and you can access it at `http://<your domain>:<port>/api-json`

Answer (score 0):

```
In NestJS, you can use the @nestjs/swagger package to generate Swagger documentation for your API. This package provides decorators that allow you to add Swagger metadata to your controllers, methods, parameters, and responses.

To generate a Swagger JSON or YAML file, you can use the SwaggerModule provided by the @nestjs/swagger package. This module has a setup method that takes in a configuration object where you can specify the location of your Swagger file.
```